# PHP store session data in class

Tags: php, database, class, session

I am working on storing PHP session variables to the database, and there are some concerns. I wonder if you guys can give me a better solution or if anything wrong in my understanding please tell me. Thank you.

First, I store user inputs in PHP session variables. I can not insert this session data to the database yet because I need to wait for another user input (this input will insert to the database at the same time as the session data). The session has a time limit (60 seconds). I need a place to store the session data temporarily. If the session is over, the data is gone.

I am thinking the place to store the session data will be the object. Maybe making a class to store the session data. When the user gives another input, extract the data from that object and insert into the database. I haven't used any object-oriented concepts in PHP, so I wonder whether this process will work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are really trying to do here.  Why not just store the session data in session?  In other words, why make some session-like storage when you already have session storage?  When you get this second input (which needs to trigger database insert) just grab the information needed from session and insert it into the DB along with this input information.  Do you needed the session data itself (without being combined with input data) to be stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, I insert session data into database two times. Once I insert session data, and I need insert those session data combined with input data.(Separate table). I am worrying session time is over while user type the second input so I lost that session data. That's why I was thinking about another storage.

Comment: Your session expiry won't be changed by the fact you store session data in the database. If you change all your session handlers to use database, the sessions will still expire according to your session timeout settings.

Comment: _“The session has a time limit (60 seconds). I need a place to store the session data temporarily.”_ – isn’t that what a session _is_ – a _temporary_ data storage mechanism? I can’t figure out what your actual problem is – if 60 secs session lifetime is not enough, then why not just set it up?

Answer (score 3):

The way i handle sessions is using singleton pattern:

```
class Session {
    private static $_instance;
    private $id;
    private $data;

    private function __clone() {}
    private function __construct() {
        session_start();

        $this->id   = session_id();
        $this->data =& $_SESSION;
    }

    public static function open() {
        if ( ! (self::$_instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

   public function __set($name, $value) {
     $this->data[$name] = $value;
   }

   public function __get($name) {
     return isset($this->data[$name]) ? $this->data[$name] : null;
   }
}
```

this way your session data is stored in **$data** variable and are accessible through overloading.